# AWS Amplify federatedSignIn for multiple SAML providers

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, saml, aws-amplify

We need to support multiple identity providers on Cognito, therefore there will be multiple identity provider configuration will be set as SAML.

But I know that we need to provide the providerName as customProvider on AWS Amplify

```
const resp = await Auth.federatedSignIn({customProvider:'customSamlProviderName'})
```

how can we provide multiple providerName to Auth.federatedSignIn object? I just want to show only single login button for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As multiple identity provider name is not supported on

```
Auth.federatedSignIn({customProvider: 'providerName'})
```

we have decided to implement Home Realm Discovery, to fetch the relevant identity provider name by customer and dynamically set on `Auth.federatedSignIn` call.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact use case. When I use below, it gives me an error saying `Login option is not available. Please try another one` on the Cognito endpoint page.

```
Auth.federatedSignIn({
 customProvider: 'customSamlProviderName',
 customState: 'something',
}}
```

But if I use `window.location.assign(http://{cognito-endpoint}//oauth2/authorize&idp_identifier=customSamlProviderName)`, it works well.

Is there no way I can put `idp_identifier` in the `federatedSignIn` call?

Comment: Hello, we have decided to implement "Home Realm Discovery", which is a new login screen asks user to enter her email and fetch the relevant identity provider name stored on db and then front end passes it to Auth.federatedSignIn call as a customProvider. 

If your customer's email domain is always the same for an idp, you may even not need that -> you can set idp name as domain name for instance.

Comment: Thanks, @Gok, that's what I thought as well. It's a shame that `federatedSignIn` doesn't do a `pre-authorization` Lambda trigger (which may have resolved my use case). I'll have to create an endpoint to do an idp check -> `federatedSignIn` on success. The question I have is, is there a Cognito endpoint to check all the idp's it holds?

Comment: Although I'll have to look at Home Realm Discovery. Our clients don't necessarily have Azure AD so I am not sure how will it work.